# Stack Overflow doesn't recognise my Ask Ubuntu login

Tags: support, auto-login

Suddenly, today, Stack Overflow is asking me to log in.  I have an Ask Ubuntu account linked to my Launchpad account.

I can log into Ask Ubuntu OK, and then I can go to anywhere in the network, Server Fault, [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), etc., even Meta.SE....but not Stack Overflow.

The dropdown shows me comments and points from Stack Overflow, too, and I can go there, but it looks like I'm logged out.

Does anyone else have this issue today?

**UPDATE 1: 2019-09-01**

- The issue is in Chrome Version 78.0.3904.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Firefox works ok (Can log into SO).
- Chrome Incognito mode works ok (Can log into SO).
- I have disabled all extensions in Chrome but the issue still occurs - so it's NOT an extension issue.

**UPDATE 2: 2019-11-01**

**It's now got worse!**  I have also tried logging out and in using different Launchpad options.  Even with "Change all private data" it still won't let me go from any site to SO.

**To be clear, this issue is *only* with Stack Overflow (and SO Meta).  There must be something specific to SO + Chrome + Launchpad that's causing this bug.**

Comment: Did you check to see if third-party cookies (cross-site cookies) aren't disallowed?

Comment: I don't see any errors to that effect.  Only quant.js was blocked.  But I disabled by ad blockers and it had no effect.  I don't see why cross-site cookies would work for everything *except* SO, though, if they're all part of the same network.

Comment: So no problems when you visited serverfault.com or superuser.com?

Comment: Nope, as I said in the question, the issue is *only* with SO.  No issues with any other SE site (specifically those in the question are ones I tested.)

Comment: I disagree with closing it so soon as I just reproduced it!  It seems to occur after approximately 2 weeks.  Meanwhile, obligatory xkcd: https://www.xkcd.com/583/